# How can I extract data from pdf file

Tags: extract

I have a pdf file that contains many tables. It is a long file (35 pages)..
I tried to import tables through excel, but never worked. Tried some tools online and it doesn't work too. Any suggestions???
Thanks in advance

I have tried also a python program proposed by chat gbt, bit it doesn't work too

Comment: The best approach depends on how exactly is your PDF file is structured and what exactly you are aiming to extract from it. For instance, If the PDF contains searchable, you can probably use a [PDF Library](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/pdf) directly. If the PDF is instead made up of images obtained from scanned pages, you would need [OCR](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/ocr). Please provide an example of the PDF you are trying to extract data from and show how you’d like to output to look like. (Disclaimer: I am an employee of the vendor of the linked example libraries)